# SQL between-statement

Tags: sql

In SQL I want to call all prices between 3 and 4. I entered the next code that doesn't work. What do I need to do to make it work?

code

```
SELECT * FROM `album` WHERE `prijs` BETWEEN 3 en AND 4
```

Comment: Remove that `en`.

Comment: Why does anyone even bother answering those.

Comment: For future reference, saying something "doesn't work" is not a very good problem description. Always, at the very least, include any error message you receive.

Comment: `between` is an operator, not a "statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below - you've a syntax error in your query, remove `en`

```
SELECT * FROM `album` WHERE `prijs` BETWEEN 3 AND 4
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
SELECT * FROM `album` WHERE `prijs` BETWEEN 3 AND 4
```